# Why is my filter function only working when it has two arguments, even though one argument is missing?

Tags: javascript, filter, arguments

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is to filter out only the indices I need. However I noticed that it only works when passing BOTH filter(v,i) into the method, even though v is never used! At first I believed this was a scoping issue, but v is never declared globally.

The computation below works fine:

```
 wordObj.wordKeys[0] = wordObj.wordKeys[0].filter((v, i) => {
    return indiciesToKeep.includes(i);
  });
```

However, this computation without "v" does not:

```
 wordObj.wordKeys[0] = wordObj.wordKeys[0].filter((i) => {
    return indiciesToKeep.includes(i);
  });
```

It is not throwing any syntax errors. It is simply just not returning the correct indices when I don't pass "v" into function. Any ideas on why this may not work would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First parameter is the item. Second parameter is the index. If you need to use the index, you need two parameters. The names for them are completely arbitrary, you could call them `tom` and `jerry`, if you wish - the second one is still going to be the index. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Oh ok. So even though it shows that it is greyed out in vscode, meaning "not used", it will still keep track of the elements index. That makes sense. Thank you!